# Adding custom stylesheet into header.php using a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, headers

I have a bunch of code that I tend to put into the `header.php` of every site I do which are specific to Internet Explorer.

I was wondering if there was a way to insert code into a 'standard' `header.php`.

Yes, I can simply modify the header. But the idea is to make this a plugin which is generic.

Specifically, I'd like to create a plugin to echo the following in the header immediately after the default stylesheet:

```css
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, I'd like to create a plugin to echo the following in the
>   header immediately after the default stylesheet

The preferred way is to *enqueue* it, with the default/main stylesheet as the *dependency*.

Here's a demo plugin, with the structure:

```
+ plugins/
|
+--+ my-ie-style/
   |    
   +--+ my-ie-style.php
   |
   +--+ css/
      |
      +--+ ie.css
```

where the `my-ie-style.php` file is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Demo - My IE style
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85496/26350
 * Description: Enqueue With IE conditional, depending on the main-style stylesheet
 * Author:      wpse
 * Version:     1.0.0
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    // Register
    wp_register_style( 
       'my-ie-style',                                 // handle
       plugin_dir_url( __FILE__  ) . 'css/ie.css',    // file
       [ 'main-style' ],                              // dependency    <-- ADJUST THIS!
       '1.0.0',                                       // version
       'all'                                          // media
    );

    // Enqueue
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-ie-style' );

    // Add IE conditional
    wp_style_add_data( 
        'my-ie-style',  // handle
        'conditional',  // key ('conditional', 'rtl', 'suffix', 'after', 'alt', 'title')
        'IE'            // value
    );
} );
```

This will generate the following within the `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' 
      id='main-style-css'  
      href='http://example.tld/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css?ver=4.5.3' 
      type='text/css' 
      media='all' />

<!--[if IE]>
<link rel='stylesheet' 
      id='my-ie-style-css' 
      href='http://example.tld/wp-content/plugins/my-ie-style/css/ie.css?ver=1.0.0' 
      type='text/css' 
      media='all' />
<![endif]-->
```

where our *custom* IE stylesheet loads after the *main* stylesheet.

Hopefully you can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Fabulous! I -knew- there had to be a way that worked within the WP core. Big Cheers! Opens up a number of other possibilities.

Comment: Erm, where do i add that first part?

Comment: Please check the updated the answer  @greenleader

Answer (score 0):

You want `wp_enqueue_style()`. It's considered best practice and all around more elegant than hooking into the wp_head.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: What would one do about the `IE` checking using `wp_enqueue_style`?